# implementing bootstrap-datepicker with a link and text

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a text label and a link with 2 arrow button in which I need to implement a calendar widget.
I am currently using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) which come very handy for my other pages as well.

But they are text fields so I found no problems in implementing it.

[image: my widget]

But here I don't have a text input.
I have a label which need to be updated based on selected calendar date and on clicking the arrow the date need to be incremented and shown. Not sure how to trigger these event into the calendar using bootstrap-datepicker.

Tried to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/5t44wvdh/) but not sure how to get the external library working.

Code:

```
<div class="calendar-widget"> <a><span><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-fw"></i></span></a>

     <h3> Today, 17 Nov </h3>
 <a class="click-pick"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i></span>
                                  <input type="hidden" id="click-picker"/>
                              </a>
 <a><span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-fw"></i></span></a>

</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".click-pick").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$(".click-pick").click(function () {
    $(".click-pick").datepicker('show');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootstrap-datepicker library which you are using can be triggered on any element, not necessarily a text `input` or a `form-group`. However, it will not be able to update the date because there is no `input` target. You will have to hook into its relevant `method` calls and `event`s which this component exposes.

In short, you will have to use:

1. `.datepicker().on('changeDate', <callback>);` : for hooking its date change event, and
2. `.datepicker("setDate", <Date>);` : to set its date depending on your left-right arrows.

You will also need to get the selected date from the `datepicker` component using its `changeDate` event handler parameter. The `changeDate` event handler function receives a parameter called `e`, from which you can extract the selected date.

As per the documentation here: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
        .on(picker_event, function(e){
            # `e` here contains the extra attributes
});
```

Of particular interest to us are:

1. `e.date`: returns the selected date
2. `e.format([idx], [format])`: returns the selected date in a particular format. We don't need `idx` because we have only one datepicker. `format` specifies the format in which to return the date. We can omit this as well because if absent, the format set on the datepicker will be used.

Hope that helps you understand better.

***Here is a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ecL5p0xa/1/***

***Demo Snippet***:

```js
var curDate = new Date();  // Global or Namespace scoped variable to hold current date

$('#calIcon').datepicker({ // Initialize the datepicker with your options
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', dateChanged); // Hook the changeDate event to fire "dateChanged"

function dateChanged(e) {            // The handler for changeDate event
    $("#dtLabel").text(e.format());  // get the selected date in specified format 
    curDate = e.date;                // cache the selected date in the global variable
}

$("#calIcon").datepicker("setDate", new Date()); // Seed the datepicker with today

$(".glyphicon-chevron-left").on("click", function() {  // on click of left arrow
    curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() - 1);            // decrement current date by 1
    $("#calIcon").datepicker("setDate", curDate);      // set datepicker to new date
});
$(".glyphicon-chevron-right").on("click", function() { // on click of right arrow
    curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);            // increment current date by 1
    $("#calIcon").datepicker("setDate", curDate);      // set datepicker to new date
});
```

```css
.nav {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.nav span, .nav label { margin-right: 8px; }
#calIcon, .glyphicon-chevron-left, .glyphicon-chevron-right { 
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
#calIcon:hover, .glyphicon-chevron-left:hover, .glyphicon-chevron-right:hover { 
    background-color: #eee; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="row nav">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <label id="dtLabel">Today</label>
        <span id="calIcon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't explain better than this. Thanks a lot. will try this and will update.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: it is bad that I can upvote only once. you are just awesome :)